# Why are my Rails assets getting precompiled twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, activeadmin

I've noticed my assets seem to get compiled twice, which considerably slows down my deployment, as this step is the most time consuming part:

```
~/projects/rewportal(mapwidget ✔) rake assets:precompile
/home/ruy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby /home/ruy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rewportal/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
AssetSync: using /home/ruy/projects/rewportal/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
AssetSync: using /home/ruy/projects/rewportal/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
AssetSync: Syncing.
Using: Directory Search of /home/ruy/projects/rewportal/public/assets
Uploading: assets/application-5170f52c1dd49cb382d5135bee01d75e.js
[...]
Fetching files to flag for delete
Flagging 8 file(s) for deletion
Deleting: assets/active_admin-4ce46d089d4b0080e87c9abcb6fa6c97.css
[...]
AssetSync: Done.
```

It this normal?

When I precompile to other environments (non-production), I can see the detailed compilation of each asset twice:

```
~/projects/rewportal(mapwidget ✔) rake RAILS_ENV=qa assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/home/ruy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby /home/ruy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rewportal/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=qa RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
AssetSync: using /home/ruy/projects/rewportal/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
Compiled gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js  (141ms)  (pid 8480)
Compiled gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js  (148ms)  (pid 8480)
[...]
Compiled active_admin.css  (1299ms)  (pid 8480)
Compiled active_admin/print.css  (113ms)  (pid 8480)
** Invoke assets:precompile:nondigest (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
AssetSync: using /home/ruy/projects/rewportal/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:nondigest
Compiled gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js  (133ms)  (pid 8480)
Compiled gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js  (133ms)  (pid 8480)
[...]
Compiled active_admin.css  (1290ms)  (pid 8480)
Compiled active_admin/print.css  (116ms)  (pid 8480)
AssetSync: Syncing.
Using: Directory Search of /home/ruy/projects/rewportal/public/assets
Uploading: assets/active_admin-d05b61ab8366b74eabc9074d3e60fe82.css.gz
[...]
Fetching files to flag for delete
Flagging 6 file(s) for deletion
Deleting: assets/active_admin-ec90e7d9a9f45f14d1387f58fa1452b4.css
[...]
AssetSync: Done.
```

My `application.rb` has the following:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( active_admin/print.css active_admin.css active_admin.js admin.js admin.css html5shiv.js )
```

Ideas?

Comment: I think this is not normal. Try to use **foreman start** on the local host.

Comment: So it seems like it is not Heroku specific. I ran `rake assets:precompile` and it also did it twice. I'll update the title and details.

Comment: Have the exact same issue. Everything works, but it seems like waste to run this twice.

Comment: There's an initializer in active_admin that adds its asset files to the precompile list; maybe the line you added in `application.rb` is a duplicate. What happens if you comment it out?

Comment: This is normal. The precompilation task first compiles your assets into primary format, then into digest format (ie. with the MD5 fingerprint).

Answer (score 12):

Rails 3 by default compiles once to generate fingerprinted assets, and once to generate non-fingerprinted assets (the fingerprinted ones have the MD5 hash in the filename).

You can use the [turbo-sprockets-rails3 gem](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3) to create both from one compilation.

In Rails 4, this functionality was extracted into the [sprockets-rails gem](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails) and the behavior was changed, so the double compilation does not happen in Rails 4.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using capistrano? If so, you can try to compile your assets locally, and then upload to server, with a task like this

```
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :assets do
    desc "Precompile assets on local machine and upload them to the server."
    task :precompile, roles: :web, except: {no_release: true} do
      run_locally "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
      find_servers_for_task(current_task).each do |server|
        run_locally "rsync -vr --exclude='.DS_Store' public/assets #{user}@#{server.host}:#{shared_path}/"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I overwrite the deploy_all task inside deploy.rb to compile before uploading:

```
task :remake_all do
  puts "precompiling assets"
  res = `env rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=precompile RAILS_GROUPS=assets 2>&1`

  $stderr.puts "assets res is: #{res}"
  if res =~ /aborted|don't|invalid|segmentation|bug/i
    puts "############  Unable to compile assets  #########" 
    exit
  end
end
```

I had issues with the development environment not compiling properly and the production environment needing access to mysql servers behind a firewall, so made a new environment called :precompile

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me (Rails 3) was to run `rake assets:precompile:primary` instead of `rake assets:precompile:all`.